# Chef: Can a variable set within one ruby_block be used later in a recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops

Let's say I have one variable, `directory_list`, which I define and set in a ruby_block named `get_directory_list`. Can I use `directory_list` later on in my recipe, or will the compile/converge processes prevent this?

Example:

```
ruby_block "get_file_list" do
    block do
        transferred_files = Dir['/some/dir/*']
    end
end

transferred_files.each do |file|
    file "#{file}" do
        group "woohoo"
        user "woohoo"
    end
end
```

Comment: I feel like someone asked this question today on Freenode in #chef, repeatedly.

Comment: It's certainly possible. Sounds like someone REALLY wanted an answer.

Comment: Hahahaha. @grill good one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Option 1: You could also put your file resource inside the ruby_block.

```
ruby_block "get_file_list" do
    block do
        files = Dir['/some/dir/*']

        files.each do |f|
            t = Chef::Resource::File.new(f)
            t.owner("woohoo")
            t.group("woohoo")
            t.mode("0600")
            t.action(:create)
            t.run_context=(rc)
            t.run_action(:create)
        end

    end
end
```

Option 2: You could use node.run_state to pass data around.

```
ruby_block "get_file_list" do
    block do
        node.run_state['transferred_files'] = Dir['/some/dir/*']
    end
end

node.run_state['transferred_files'].each do |file|
    file "#{file}" do
        group "woohoo"
        user "woohoo"
    end
end
```

Option 3: If this were just one file, you could declare a file resource with `action :nothing`, look up the resource from within the ruby_block, and set the filename, and then notify the file resource when the ruby_block runs.

Option 4: If this is the example from IRC today, just place your rsync and the recursive chown inside a single bash resource. rsync and chown are already idempotent, so I don't think it's objectionable in this particular case.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't even know these options were possible. Thanks for the assist.